# A set with infinity Hausdorff measure, but Hausdorff dimension $\frac{\log2}{\log3}$

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory-analysis, fractal-analysis

I am going through the text 'Fractal Geometry: Mathematical Foundations and Applications' and came the following exercise:

Give a set $B\subset\mathbb{R}$ that has Hausdorff dimension $s=\frac{\log2}{\log3}$ but has $H^s(B)=\infty$.

My thoughts:

Now, when I see $\frac{\log2}{\log3}$ the first thing that comes to mind is the cantor set $C$, but the $H^s(C)$ is finite. I feel as though I am missing a lemma or theorem. Is there some relation of the Hausdorff dimension of a set constructed by countable unions?

Comment: If the union is nice enough (e.g. not two of the sets are nearer than a given $\delta > 0$), the Hausdorff dimension of the union is the supremum of the dimensions of the parts. Also note that Hausdorff measures are translation-invariant.

Comment: So ive I took a countable number of cantor sets, some $\delta>0$ apart, then the Hausdorff dimension would still be $s$ but, the Hausdorff measure $\infty$?

Comment: If your starting set has $H^s(C) > 0$. In this situation, the positive distance isn't needed (that's just a condition that works in every metric space), it suffices that there's no overlap.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3686906/set-with-hausdorff-dimension-s-log-2-log-3-but-hs-infty looks similar

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695680/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hausdorff measure of Cantor set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3695680/hausdorff-measure-of-cantor-set)